# I am getting error Formula expression is required for attribute value in visualforce page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

> Error: Formula expression is required for attribute value in
>    in q4controller at line 7 column 58

**VF code**

```
        <apex:pageblock title = "List of accounts">

                <apex:pageblocktable value="{! acts }" var="a">

                    <apex:column value="{ !a.Name } " /> 
                    <apex:column value="{ !a.Type }" />    
                    <apex:column value="{ !a.Industry }" />

                </apex:pageblocktable>


       </apex:pageblock>


</apex:page>
```

******Controller class******

```
Public class q4{

List<account> acts;

public list<account> getacts(){
acts = [Select name,type,industry from account where type = 'Prospect'];
return acts;
}



}
```

what is this error, i don't understand. i have tried googling but wasnt able to pin point what the issue is.also i am new to this so please scuse and silly mistake.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove extra space from your column. They are giving you error.

```
 <apex:column value="{!a.Name } " /> 
 <apex:column value="{!a.Type }" />    
 <apex:column value="{!a.Industry }" />
```

Comment: Oops,silly mistake.
Thanks